# Why is _.maxBy in loash not returning an undefineable type?

Tags: typescript, lodash

See this code:

```
const studentHeights: { 
     name: string; 
     height: number; 
     year: 'senior'|'junior'|'sophomore'|'freshman' 
   }[] = [];
const tallestSenior = _.chain(studentHeights)
    .filter((student) => student.year === 'senior')
    .maxBy((student) => student.height)
    .value();
```

What type do you expect tallestSenior to be?

I would expect it to be: `{ name: string; height: number, year: ... } | undefined` or nullable.

In my VSCode with typescript, it is giving me a nonnullable: `{ name: string; height: number; year: ...}`. This will, of course, cause bugs during runtime.

Note that: `_.maxBy(studentHeights, (student) => student.height))` has the correct typing with undefineable.

My package.json has:

- "typescript": "~4.1.5"
- "lodash": "^4.17.21",

Any help?

Comment: The undefined will only appear in VSCode if you are running in strict mode e.g. if you have `strict: true` under compilerOptions in tsconfig.json.

Comment: Thank you! Anything else I need? Strict mode seems to not be picking it up. Here's my tsconfig.json: 

```{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "allowJs": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "exclude": ["lib", "node_modules", "ot_utils"]
}```